# Services tab not appears -Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

> `Services` tab does not appear in the WordPress dashboard? How do
>   we create services? any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: hey @mohammad-usman what `Services` are you referring to? In default WP there is nothing like that, I guess you have some theme / plugin that brings that option and you have to reach out to author of it and seek for help

Comment: in the old version of WordPress, there were services but later on, there isn't one

Comment: where exactly? I have old WP install and still can't locate it?